# How to make Django Template Dynamically update without refreshing page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have A django tempalate that i use to render values that are selected from database.
I want the page to update the data without refreshing the page.
Here is my template code section.

```
{% for history in upload_history %}



 <tr style="background-color:#FFFF99 ;height:20px;">
        <td>{{history.file_path}}</td>
        <td><strong style="background-color:#B0B0B0 ;"><a  href="#response-from-server">Failed</a></strong></td>
        <td><strong >{{history.failed}}</strong></td>
        <td><strong >{{history.datetime}}</strong></td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
     {% for histo in upload_history %}
    <tr style="background-color:#FFFFCC ;height:20px;">
        <td>{{histo.file_path}}</td>
        <td><strong style="background-color:#00FF00 ;">Successful</strong></td>
        <td><strong >{{histo.successful}}</strong></td>
        <td><strong >{{histo.datetime}}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

And here is the view code snnippet where i hit the database

```
def up(request):
    items  = Tzworksjmplist.objects.values('evidence').distinct()
    upload_history=Upload_history.objects.all().order_by('datetime')[:1]
    upload_history=Upload_history.objects.all().order_by('datetime').reverse()[:1]
```

Regards

Comment: You should read something about ajax, json and Django..and next back here again :)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to send an Ajax request to Django so you can update your template without a page load.
You will need to add some JQuery code to perform an AJAX request.
Write a Django view which will accept the request and will return a response in JSON/XML format.

```
def up(request):
    import json
    upload_history =  your orm query  to fetch data 
    json_data = json.dumps( obj_list )
    return HttpResponse( json_data, mimetype='application/json' )
```

from your template you can hit an Ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url:"/updata/",
success: function(data)
{
    alert("i got data now i will parse it as i want to display it");
},

})
```

Please don't forget to call JQuery library.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, it seems to work. it prints the alert meaning i have tyhe data,and how do i render the data in the template tags? what are the variables here? is it {{data.datetime}} for instance?

Comment: You can take a look into some tutorials available over internet .You can accept answer if it helps you. thanks